# Determine f'(x) from first principles if f(x)=$-5x^{2\ }+\ x$ . Hence calculate the tangent to f(x) where x=1.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, tangent-line

So what I did to find the answer to the first part of the question is:
f'(x)=$-10x+1$

I worked this out fine but when I got to the second part, it got a bit confusing. This is what I did:
Substituted $x=1$

$y=-5(1)^2+1$

and got $y= -4$

Then used the equation of the tangent:
$y-y_1=m\left(x-x_1\right)$ which leads to
$y+4=-5\left(x-1\right)$
$y=-5x+1$

But the memo says this is incorrect. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: You should use Latex to edit your question… it is almost impossible to read currently.

Comment: And please put the *whole* formulas inside the dollar signs.

Comment: You missed the minus sign in front of the $5x^2$, and plugging in 1 into the derivative was also done incorrectly.

Comment: @BreakingBioinformatics please explain?

Comment: $f'(1) = -9$, not $-5$.  So, the correct answer is $y+4 = -9(x-1)$, or $9x+y-5 = 0$

Comment: isn't f'(x) a y value and cannot be used as the gradient of the equation?

Comment: $f'$ is always a rate of change, i.e., slope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are asked to find the equation of tangent to the curve $f(x) = -5x^2+x$ at $x = 1$.

When $x=1$ then value of $y$ will be,

$\implies f(1) = -5(1)^2 + (1)\\
\implies f(1) = -5 + 1 = -4$

Therefore, we got a point $(1,-4)$ from where the line passes.

Slope of the tangent at $x=1$ is given by $f'(1) = -9$.

**So, using point slope form:-**

$\implies (y-(-4)) = -9(x-1)\\$

$\implies (y+4) = -9x+9\\$

$\implies y = -9x+9-4\\$

$\implies y = -9x+5\\$

Therefore the required equation is $y = -9x + 5$